# What's the meaning of "water down"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is a passage from an article on the origin of the idiom *fall off the wagon*:

> The term references the water wagons which were once drawn by horses to water down dirt roads so that they did not become dusty.

What does *water down* mean? Does it simply mean *to water* like watering plants and the *down* is just there to add emphasis because the water pours downwards? I looked up the phrase and I couldn't find any definitions relevant to the context. The senses of *water down* I found are:

> 1. to make a liquid weaker by adding water
> 2. to change a speech, a piece of writing, etc. in order to make it less strong or offensive

Comment: In this context, to *water down the road* simply means to ***wet** the road*. This is made clear by the remainder of the sentence, which explains that this was being done *so that they did not become dusty.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: This is a really cool question. I checked at least five dictionaries, and only found the two meanings listed here. Yet the phrase sounded [perfectly natural to me](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22water+down+the+infield%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22water+down+the+infield%22&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=MKa1UYaHKIuErQHe24CIAg&ved=0CA0Q_AUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aWM&fp=2bb77c0ff9fb9356&biw=1224&bih=876). Gotta love it when an ELL member finds a deficiency in published dictionaries.

Comment: @J.R.: You can hardly expect dictionaries to list every possible preposition in such contexts. In my *brush* examples, for instance, I'd say that only *brush **up*** (and maybe *brush **off***) can ever really be "phrasal verbs", and in my specific contexts they don't apply anyway.

Comment: @Fumble: I'm not marveling that the dictionaries don't list "every possible preposition." I only marveled that they have a separate listing for this particular preposition, but don't list all the meanings. (It's common for a meaning to be missed here and there, but I can usually find _some_ dictionary that will list that extra meaning.) You needn't marvel if you don't want to; I'm going to keep marveling despite your pooh-poohing. Don't water down my joy. ;^)

Comment: @J.R.: Well, *phrasal verb* isn't a very precise category, but I'm reasonably happy to accept *water down = dilute* as (just about) one of them. I'm far less convinced about, say *brush off/away = dismiss*, but I'd definitely expect a decent dictionary to list *brush up = review/reconsolidate previously-acquired knowledge*. I'd also note that you can *water **up*** a steam locomotive or ship, for example, (replenish onboard water supplies for the engine or passengers) - but it would have to be a *very* comprehensive dictionary to list that usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As OP has already established, there's a [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) to [water **down**](http://online-english-lessons.eu/wordpress/2011/06/phrasal-verb-water-down/) (literally and figuratively, to [dilute](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilute)). But that's not relevant to the cited usage here, where it simply means [to [make] wet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wet). Per my comment, this is clear from the context, which explicitly says that the roads were dampened to reduce the dust.

OP is correct in supposing that *down* in this instance simply refers to the fact that the water is splashed ***down[wards]*** onto the road. But I think it's fair to say the semantic content of the word is negligible here, since the meaning should be just as clear even if it's omitted.

---

Taking a different verb, it can be seen that [optional] prepositions are often added after common verbs of action where the [minimal] semantic content of the preposition can be largely ignored...

> He ate his tea in a hurry, [brushed **up**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22brushed%20up%20his%20jacket%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) his jacket, and started off.
>    The man lifted himself off of the ground, [brushed **off**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22brushed%20up%20his%20jacket%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22brushed%20off%20his%20jacket%22&oq=%22brushed%20off%20his%20jacket%22&gs_l=serp.3...56703.57714.0.58346.5.5.0.0.0.0.87.319.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.1w-pfvA5bIE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=575db4e7c24bc40c&biw=1296&bih=930) his jacket and walked away.
>    He stood before the mirror while his valet [brushed **out**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22brushed%20up%20his%20jacket%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22brushed%20out%20his%20jacket%22&oq=%22brushed%20out%20his%20jacket%22&gs_l=serp.3...66116.69519.0.70382.8.7.1.0.0.0.91.560.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.16.psy-ab.jFPoPKcOpKI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=575db4e7c24bc40c&biw=1296&bih=930) his jacket.

In those examples, native speakers would be unlikely to register any difference in meaning if those prepositions were transposed - or more importantly, if they were omitted altogether.

In my examples, to [brush **up**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=brush+up&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Nd21UYTwHMek0QWroYHoBg&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=c5d308b017113301&biw=1296&bih=930) can sometimes be a "phrasal verb" *(to review; refresh one's memory)* - but that clearly doesn't fit the context, so it can be discounted.

My advice in such contexts is to consider the possibility of a phrasal verb usage, but if that doesn't quickly suggest a credible interpretation, assume the preposition isn't particularly significant. Often it'll be an almost random choice (but don't add such prepositions yourself unless you're familiar with the usage).

Comment: Could "down" be referring to ensuring that dust does not go up?

Comment: @Andrew: Well, as I said, it seems unlikely to me that most native speakers really bother to think about exactly what (if anything) the word *down* reflects here. Note that we often [hose **down**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hose+down+the+patio%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) or [hose **off**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hose+off+the+patio%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) a patio, for example. Probably *down* because that's where you direct the water, or *off* because you're sluicing debris off/away from the paved area.